# How to use a gsp template to create a text file?

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy, io

I have used the [Grails Rendering Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rendering) in the past with much success in creating PDFs.  Throw now I would like to create a simple text file, using a gsp.  I loved the ease of using a model to define how to insert information into the template. I realize I don't need to render a text file, but is there a similar way to use a template to just create an ordinary text file?

Example from how to render a jpg using the Grails Render Plugin: (notice the model use)

```
    def bytes = gifRenderingService.render(template: '/images/coupon', model: [serial: 12345])
// Render to a file
    new File("coupon.jpg").withOutputStream { outputStream ->
        jpegRenderingService.render(template: '/images/coupon', model: [serial: 12345])
    }
```

If there isn't an easy way like the above example, since my information is coming from multiple domain classes should I just create `<g>` tags in my gsp template that pulls based on conditions needed? If that is the case.. how would I insert a variable into my gsp template from my service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might take a look at the `grails.gsp.PageRenderer` utility class.  It allows you to render .gsp templates as a `String`:

```
String gspOutput = groovyPageRenderer.render(view: '<your view>.gsp', model: [ modelObj1: ... ])
```

... or directly to a `Writer` or `OutputStream`:

```
groovyPageRenderer.renderTo(view: '<your view>.gsp', model: [ modelObj1: ... ], <writer or OS>)
```

Much more detail can be found here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/03/grails-goodness-render-gsp-views-and.html

Answer (score 0):

To render the template as text file you should set the content type of the response to text/plain

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you just create your text template as standard, with <g> tags etc..., then call the standard grails render() function on the template with a contentType of 'text/plain'.  No plugin necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the GSP file

```
<%@page contentType="text/plain"%>
```